# How to pass Configuration parameters to Flink Docker image via docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, apache-flink

I want to pass below configuration parameters to docker-compose.yml for flink docker image.

```
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://.../flink/checkpoint
state.savepoints.dir: s3://.../flink/savepoint
s3.access-key: ...
s3.secret-key: ...
jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy: region
```

Can someone help me on how to do it ?

docker image - flink:1.9.0

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is looking for the answer, add double quote around the whole entry of FLINK_PROPERTIES to escape the colon:

```
jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.9-scala_2.11
    command: "jobmanager.sh start-foreground"
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/opt/flink/conf
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - "FLINK_PROPERTIES=a: b \nc: d"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mount a config folder into the container

You can create a volume that mounts a folder from the host system to the location of the Flink configuration in the Docker container.

The [Flink Operations Playground](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/getting-started/docker-playgrounds/flink-operations-playground.html) is doing this to pass custom configuration to the Flink Docker image.

The entry for the JobManager in the [`docker-compose.yaml`](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml) could look like this:

```
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.9-scala_2.11
    command: "jobmanager.sh start-foreground"
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/opt/flink/conf
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
```

It would mount the `./conf` folder (which should be next to the `docker-compose.yaml` file) to `/opt/flink/conf` in the Docker container which is the location that FLink takes its configuration from.

### Pass arguments via an environment variable

An alternative could be to pass configuration arguments via an environment variable.

The [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-flink/docker-flink/blob/master/1.9/scala_2.12-debian/docker-entrypoint.sh) script, which is used to start the Flink container, seems to append the content of the `FLINK_PROPERTIES`  variable to the configuration file. However, I haven't used that approach yet.

Comment: Thanks, @Fabian. I am using a mount folder solution but it is not flexible/dynamic. If I want to pass some values or change a few configurations when running jobmanager/taskmanager, it would be very convenient via environment variables. So, I am looking for "How to use FLINK_PROPERTIES".